# What is this iPad app name?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

Below are screenshots are of an iPad screensaver, the screensaver appears to be showcasing an application. The store staff were not aware of the name of this app. It appears to be a drawing app ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This application is the freemium app [Concepts](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/concepts-sketch-design-illustrate/id560586497?mt=8).

[image]

Comment: +1 this is correct, added an image from [here](http://www.stuff.tv/features/24-best-apps-your-new-apple-ipad-pro) to show it.